# Generate PDF document with Unicode characters using java and itext

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, itext

I try to adapt a standard code from the itext examples printing some additional Unicode symbols. Although the used font supports these characters, I do not get any result. (the last character "\u2609" is not printed to pdf)

Thanks in advance!

```
    /*
     * These examples are written by Bruno Lowagie in the context of an article about fonts.
     */
    package sandbox.fonts.tutorial;

    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
    import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import sandbox.WrapToTest;

    /**
     * @author Bruno Lowagie (iText Software)
     */
    @WrapToTest
    public class F07_Unicode {
        public static final String DEST = "results/fonts/tutorial/f07_unicode.pdf";
        public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
            File file = new File(DEST);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            new F07_Unicode().createPdf(DEST);
        }

        public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
            document.open();
            Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            document.add(new Paragraph("Vous \u00eates d'o\u00f9?", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u00c0 tout \u00e0 l'heure. \u00c0 bient\u00f4t.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("Je me pr\u00e9sente.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("C'est un \u00e9tudiant.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u00c7a va?", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("Il est ing\u00e9nieur. Elle est m\u00e9decin.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("C'est une fen\u00eatre.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("R\u00e9p\u00e9tez, s'il vous pla\u00eet.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("Odkud jste?", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("Uvid\u00edme se za chvilku. M\u011bj se.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("Dovolte, abych se p\u0159edstavil.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("To je studentka.", font));
        document.add(new Paragraph("V\u0161echno v po\u0159\u00e1dku?", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("On je in\u017een\u00fdr. Ona je l\u00e9ka\u0159.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("Toto je okno.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("Zopakujte to pros\u00edm.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u041e\u0442\u043a\u0443\u0434\u0430 \u0442\u044b?", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u0423\u0432\u0438\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0441\u044f \u0432 \u043d\u0435\u043c\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e. \u0423\u0432\u0438\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0441\u044f.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u041f\u043e\u0437\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0442\u0435 \u043c\u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u042d\u0442\u043e \u0441\u0442\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0442.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u0425\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0448\u043e?", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u041e\u043d \u0438\u043d\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0435\u0440. \u041e\u043d\u0430 \u0434\u043e\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u042d\u0442\u043e \u043e\u043a\u043d\u043e.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("\u041f\u043e\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0435, \u043f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430.", font));
            document.add(new Paragraph("and \u2609 what?",font));
            document.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes you say *Although the used font supports these characters*. There are more code points in Unicode than can be physically stored in a font, so I highly doubt your allegation. (By the way: I'm the person mentioned in the header of your code snippet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `\u2609` character, known as the [SUN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2609/index.htm) character. This character is not present in the font you are using. You are using `FreeSans.ttf` and that font doesn't contain the SUN symbol.

You claim *Although the used font supports these characters*, but you don't provide any proof for this allegation. There are 1,114,112 code points available in Unicode, but a composite font can only contain 65,535 characters. It is physically impossible to store 1,114,112 glyphs in a font when you only have 65,535 characters available.

You need to provide a font that knows how to render the `\u2609` and `FreeSans.ttf` isn't such a font. Please take a look at the [SunCharacter](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/showing-special-characters#1716-suncharacter.java) example:

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/Cardo-Regular.ttf";
public static final String TEXT = "The Cardo family of fonts supports this character: \u2609";

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font f = new Font(bf, 12);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(TEXT, f);
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

In this case, we use a font that knows how to draw the ☉ character, as can be checked when you open [sun_character.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/fonts/cmp_sun_character.pdf):

[image]

The fact that this character doesn't appear when you replace `Cardo-Regular.ttf` with `FreeSans.ttf` is proof that `FreeSans.ttf` doesn't contain the ☉ character.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously the CharSelect (of KDE) does not show me the correct font symbol content of the ttf file. But using the KFontView I see it.

Comment: @Banish Some tools use substitute fonts if you ask them to show a glyph. Maybe that's what happens in the tool you looked for that specific character.